# Converting mySQL queries with subqueries to DB2 SQL query with subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I'm pretty unfamiliar with DB2 SQL sever. I'm trying to query for a total rowCount from multiple tables, like so:

```
SELECT
 SUM(COUNT)
  AS ROWS
 FROM
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE1
 UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE2
 UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE3
 UNION ALL
//ETC...
)
```

But it keeps flagging an syntax error on ")". How would I restructure this?

Comment: Try giving the subquery an alias

Comment: @paul Yes, added "AS ROWS" after  ")" and it now works fine. Want to format that as an answer and I'll check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 (and SQL Server) require that subqueries are aliased, so:

```
SELECT
 SUM(COUNT)
  AS ROWS
 FROM
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE1
 UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE2
 UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE3
 UNION ALL
//ETC...
) as subqueryAlias
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I guess it's just s syntactic quirk of SQL Server?

Comment: I have to say that I don't know why it's necessary, just that it is, and has been for many years. I generally to avoid subqueries since CTEs were introduced in Sql Server 2005.

Comment: @paul: nitpicking: CTE where not "*introduced in SQL Server 2005*". They were defined by the SQL Standard in 2003 and Microsoft implemented them in 2005. Oracle had them long before that.